# Linux C Socket:"bad file descriptor" occurs when accept() invokes

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am writing a send/receive project using linux/socket/tcp, I create some threads to send or recieve message,and use a global queue to store message 
Code:

```
void EnQueue (M_queue queue,char * message,char * target_IP,char * target_IP_BAK)
{
    char a;
    char  * m=&a;
    strcpy(m,target_IP);
    M_element node=(M_element)malloc(sizeof(struct MessageNode ));
    node->message=message;
    node->target_IP=target_IP;
    node->next=NULL;
    if(IsQueueEmpty(queue))
    {
     queue->rear=queue->front=node;
    }
    else
    {
        queue->rear->next=node;
        queue->rear=node;
    }
}
M_queue messages;
void* receive_message();
void* send_message(void* args);
int main()
{



    pthread_t in_thread,out_thread;

    messages=(M_queue)malloc(sizeof(struct MessageQueue));
    init(messages);
    int ret=pthread_create(&in_thread,NULL,receive_message,NULL);
    if(ret==-1)

    {
        perror("thread receive:");
    }

    while(1)
    {
        if(!IsQueueEmpty(messages))
        {

            M_element message=DeQueue(messages);

            pthread_create(&out_thread,NULL,send_message,(void*)message);

        }


    }
    pthread_join(in_thread,NULL);
    return 0;


}
void*  send_message(void * args)
{
  struct sockaddr_in  sockaddr_out;
  M_element message=(M_element)args;
  int cfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  if(cfd==-1)
  {
      perror("send_socket");

      exit(1);
  }
  sockaddr_out.sin_family=AF_INET;
  sockaddr_out.sin_port=htons(9734);
  printf("%s\n",message->target_IP);
  sockaddr_out.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(message->target_IP);
  int ret=connect(cfd,(struct sockaddr *)&sockaddr_out,sizeof(sockaddr_out));
  if(ret==-1)
  {
      perror("connect");
      offline_message(message->target_IP,message->message); 
      exit(1);
  }
  if(write(cfd,message->message,strlen(message->message)+1)==-1)
  {
      perror("write");
      exit(1);
  }
  close(cfd);
}
void*  receive_message()
{
    char  buf[256];
    char IP[256];
    memset(IP,0,256);
    int first_socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(first_socket==-1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    struct sockaddr_in in_socketaddr;
    in_socketaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    in_socketaddr.sin_port=htons(9999);
    in_socketaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    int ret=bind(first_socket,(struct  sockaddr *)&in_socketaddr,sizeof(in_socketaddr));
    if (ret==-1)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    ret=listen(first_socket,10);
    if(ret==-1)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    int accept_socket;


    while(1)
    {
        **//error occurs**
        **accept_socket=accept(first_socket,NULL,NULL);**
        printf("%d!",first_socket);
        if(accept_socket==-1)
        {
            perror("accept");
            exit(1);
        }
        int ret=read(accept_socket,buf,sizeof(buf));
        close(accept_socket);
        if(ret==-1)
        {
            perror("read1");
            exit(1);
        }

        findIP(buf,IP);
        **EnQueue(messages,buf,IP,IP);**
        printf("%d!",first_socket);


    }
    close(first_socket);
}
```

I send  message "test" to the appliaction , accecpt() works well
but I send message "test111111" ,"bad file descriptor" occurs when accept() invokes;
and I find the 'first_socket' changes when EnQueue() invokes,but i cant find a solution ..anyone can help me ,THX

Comment: your thread function should be of the form void*  receive_message(void *) like your send_message function is

Comment: The error you're getting is probably useless since you already called `close` between `read` and `perror`.

Comment: @cnicutar,I  change the position of close but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Can you please post the code for findIP and EnQueue functions?

Comment: @Jay Ok,findIP is a very simple funcation ,and i am sure it's ok.

Comment: your code does not compile because of some missing functions and types. if its compilable then finding problems are easier. however i can see at the first of your Enqueue function you are assigning a "one" byte storage address to a char pointer where you are storing target_IP(which is atleast 4 bytes, if its not a "IN" structure). This will lead to problem. first fix this.

Comment: @Aftnix, you are right,I change it,and it works well,i am a newbie,Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have a memory overrun. 4 bytes of test data don't overrun so much, but 10 override enough to cause trouble.

The most likely victim is the `first_socket` variable. If it's overwritten, then the second `accept` will get the wrong number.
Try to print `first_socket` just before each `accept` call, to see if I'm right.

EDIT: As mark40 comments, the `EnQueue` function overruns its `a` variable.

Comment: when i send "test1111111" In while(1){} block ,the first 'first_sokcet' is 3,the second 'first_socket' is  12678643
but when i send "test" the all first_socket is 3 ,it is strange

Comment: The first few lines of your `EnQueue()` function copy a string into a  "`char a;`" (which is only big enough for one character).